# Serialize char data type with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a class which has property whiches type is char as following

```
    [XmlRoot("Root")]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [XmlElement("Test", typeof(char))]
        public char TestProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

When value of TestProperty is 'N' and if I serialize TestClass it will produce following result:

```
    <Root>
        <Test>78</Test>
    </Root>
```

But what I want is to have following

```
    <Root>
        <Test>N</Test>
    </Root>
```

Is it possible without changing type of TestProperty to string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not AFAIK. You can cheat, though:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public char TestProperty { get; set; }

[XmlElement("Test"), Browsable(false)]
public string TestPropertyString {
    get { return TestProperty.ToString(); }
    set { TestProperty = value.Single(); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is good that I now won't try to achive that ). Then it is better opinion to change type of TestProperty to string I think.